# How do I switch to ART runtime on my Samsung Galaxy S4?

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, samsung-galaxy-s-4, art

I have Galaxy S4 and I'm trying to find the menu to switch to ART runtime, but I can't find it. The Android version is KitKat 4.4.2. Does Samsung disable this feature?

Comment: Tap on build number 7 times in settings > about phone, to enable developer options, then go into settings > developer options, select runtime...

Comment: @t0mm13b The GS4 doesn't have this option for Touchwiz ROMs, the only option is a custom Google Edition / AOSP ROM with ART Support. I've done the same myself on the I9505. ART is not fully there yet though and expect some weird glitches.

Answer (score 4):

ART is not in the GS4 Developer Options. It's not compatible with the TouchWiz UI, so it was left off the GS4 update.

Comment: *Sense* is HTC's product for their phones, and isn't on Samsung phones.

Comment: TOUCHWIZ is Samsung's UI, Sense as Dan said is HTC's one. ART is not official yet and is there for developers only. HOWEVER, you can install a custom KitKat ROM with the ART option there, but some apps are not copatible. Head over to XDA and check out some of the Google Edition ROMs and see what has ART.

Answer (score 0):

Go to settings > about phone > press build number / kernel version 7 times > back to settings and you find developer options > developer options > Runtime > ART > ok. That works for me.

Comment: On which android version are you? And are you running a custom rom not based on samsung touchwiz? Like RossC pointed out in his comment - the Galaxy S4 didn't had ART Support in 4.4.2